# Form submit variables are lost when dealing with jquery variables in PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a starting page, where the user gives some information (Email and Name) and press submit. When the second page is entered, jquery sends some variables (*dateStr*) to that second page from within that second page. However, I notice that doing so makes the form submit variables disappear. I have shown the relevant part of the code here. *YourEMail* and *YourName* turn out to be empty strings here. What mistake am I doing?

```
<?php 
$YourEMail = $_REQUEST['YourEMail']; 
$InputName = $_REQUEST['YourName'];

$dateAndTime = '';
if(isset($_POST["dateStr"]) && strlen(trim($_POST["dateStr"])) > 0)
{
    $dateAndTime = $_POST["dateStr"];
    // $dateAndTime is fine, but $YourEMail and $InputName are empty here!
    ......
}
?>
```

The jquery code to post $dateStr from within the second page is shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var dateStr = d.toLocaleString();
    $.post(window.location, {
        dateStr: dateStr
    }).success(function(data){
        $('#divMessage').replaceWith("<span style=\"color:yellow\">" + dateStr + "</span>");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Is the Form attribute action(for the Form 1) set to Post ?

Comment: Yes, In the first page, like this <form action="second_page.php" method=post>. If I don't use the jquery stuff, those variables appear fine.

Comment: How can  $_POST["dateStr"] be set , if this variable is being sent by Jquery in the second form.$_POST should only contain variables which have been sent on posting the first form . Is the form being posted again somewhere in between?

Comment: the $_REQUEST values only exist if they're posted during the current postback. They don't persist between postbacks. It sounds from your description like you've submitted a form containing email/name, then rendered a new page to the user. Then you're doing another postback from the second page, containing dateStr, but you're expecting name/email to still be present. Unless you included them in the second form as hidden fields or something, they won't be. You need store the values in between postbacks (e.g. in session, database, hidden fields, whatever)

Comment: @pythonic yep your edit confirms what I'm saying. You're expecting values from a previous postback to still be present on the second postback. Either combine it all into one form, or persist the values some other way

Comment: @ADyson: Any idea how can this be done. Can you give a small example.

Comment: well which solution is best? Can the information be submitted all in one go instead of two separate forms? That would be the simplest, and maybe easier for the user too??

Comment: I do need to send information to the second page from the client side. For example, I want to send the local machine time to the server in the second page. Maybe in the future also more information, for real time updates. So, I do need this solution.

Comment: ok well then if you want to use YourName and YourEmail during the second postback, then during the first postback you need to save the values somewhere. Session is the simplest way. Something like `$_SESSION['YourEMail'] = $_REQUEST['YourEMail'];`. Then in the second postback you can access it like this: `$YourEmail = $_SESSION['YourEmail'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem. For anybody interested, here is the solution. I would like to thank ADyson for his advice on session variables.

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
....
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    $YourEMail = $_REQUEST['YourEMail']; 
    $InputName = $_REQUEST['YourName'];

    $_SESSION["email"]  = $YourEMail;
    $_SESSION["name"]   = $InputName;
}

$dateAndTime = '';
if(isset($_POST["dateStr"]) && strlen(trim($_POST["dateStr"])) > 0)
{
    $YourEMail = $_SESSION['email']; 
    $InpuName  = $_SESSION['name'];
    $dateAndTime = $_POST["dateStr"];
    ......
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed your Jquery code a bit. Try it:-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        var d = new Date();
        var dateStr = d.toLocaleString();
        var data ={ dateStr: d.toLocaleString(),YourEmail :'<?=$_POST['YourEMail']?>',YourName : '<?=$_POST['YourName']?>'}
        $.post(window.location, data ).success(function(data){            
            $('#divMessage').replaceWith("<br /><span style=\"color:yellow\">dateStr = " 
             + dateStr + "</span>");
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
```